# Using chunked encoding in a POST request to an asmx web service on IIS 6 generates a 404

Tags: post, iis-6, asmx, http-status-code-404, chunked-encoding

I'm using a CXF client to communicate with a .net web service running on IIS 6.
This request (anonymised):

```
POST /EngineWebService_v1/EngineWebService_v1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://.../Report"
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Apache CXF 2.2.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: uat9.gtios.net
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

followed by 7 chunks of 4089 bytes and one of 369 bytes, generates the following output after the first chunk has been sent:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 103
Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2010 13:00:08 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Anyone know how to get IIS to accept chunked input for a POST?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chunked encoding should be [enabled by default](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278998). You can check your setting with:

> C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts>cscript adsutil.vbs get /W3SVC/AspEnableChunkedEncoding

The 404 makes me wonder if it's really a problem with the chunked encoding. Did you triple-check the URL?

Comment: I've been through the metabase viewer and AspEnableChunkedEncoding is enabled (and not disabled anywhere).
Do you have experience that AspEnableChunkedEncoding affects POSTed uploads as well as downloads?  The docs don't say anything about chunked POSTs.
It's not a problem with the URL, a smaller request succeeeds.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes I have but only with type="FILE" but that's still a HTTP POST. Anything in the eventlog?

Answer (score 0):

You may well have URLScan running on your server. By default URLScan is configured to reject requests that have a `transfer-encoding:` header and [URLScan sends 404 errors](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/working-with-urlscan/urlscan-faq) (which is conspicuous over a proper server-error).

> UrlScan v3.1 failures result in 404 errors and not 500 errors.
>   Searching for 404 errors in your W3SVC log will include failures due
>   to UrlScan blocking.

You will need to look at the file located in (path may differ) `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\URLScan\URLScan.ini`. Somewhere in there you will find a `[DenyHeaders]` section, that will look a bit like this (it will probably have more headers listed).

```
[DenyHeaders]

transfer-encoding:
```

Remove `transfer-encoding:` from this list and it should fix your problem.